# Pieces of strings in Lua

Tags: string, algorithm, lua, numbers

I prompt the user to input a variable 'year'.

I need to get the first 2 digits, and the last 2 digits of the 4-digit variable year for the Gaussian algorithm and store them in two separate variables.

What I need help on is getting the first 2 and last 2 numbers from 'year'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
local n = 1234
local first = math.floor(n / 100)
local last = n % 100

print(first, last)
```

which print:

```
12  34
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Bart's answer, if you're keeping it in string form you can just use `sub` to grab the parts you want:

```
year = '1969'
firsttwo = year:sub(1,2)
secondtwo = year:sub(3,4)
```